# how to make batch wait for multiple subprocesses

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wait

I have this batch file:

```
SET WINRAR="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR"
start "" %WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe a -u -m5 "Group 1.rar" "Group 1" "Group 1"
start "" %WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe a -u -m5 "Group 2.rar" "Group 2" "Group 2"
start "" %WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe a -u -m5 "Group 3.rar" "Group 3" "Group 3"
start "" "D:\"
```

I want all the rar processes to work at the same time and to open the directory `D:\` after rar finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by starting your un-rar processes without /WAIT and check whether they're finished using `tasklist`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET WINRAR="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR"
start "" %WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe a -u -m5 "Group 1.rar" "Group 1" "Group 1"
start "" %WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe a -u -m5 "Group 2.rar" "Group 2" "Group 2"
start "" %WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe a -u -m5 "Group 3.rar" "Group 3" "Group 3"

:LOOP
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq WinRAR.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "WinRAR.exe">NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    ping localhost -n 6 >nul
    GOTO LOOP
)
start "" "D:\"
```

The code does the following:

First you start all your un-rar processes. Then you check whether your tasklist contains any winrar.exe processes. If it is the case you wait 5 seconds and check again. As soon as there are no more winrar.exe entries in the task list you go on to `start "" "D:\"`.

EDIT: As you've asked what how wait by ping works, here is the explanation.
Sorry, there was a bug in my code. It's `ping localhost -n 6` and not `ping localhost -6`.

`ping localhost -n 6>nul` makes your system ping localhost 6 times with 1 second between each ping. 6 pings with 1 second between is 5 :) As localhost responds within 1 ms you are waiting about 5 seconds. `>nul` suprsses the output of the ping command in your console.

Comment: this is working fine thank you alot ... but what is -6 mean ? can you explain please ... and that mean i must write the code like this    ping localhost -6 (5) >nul  OR    ping localhost -6 >nul .. THANK YOU

Comment: I will edit my answer and explain the meaning of this.

Comment: Done. One last remark: If you want to wait for X seconds you have to do `ping localhost -n X+1`.

Comment: is there any way to get the errorlevel of the child process after it ends? unix is so much better at this. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the solution is not affordable from a batch file only. The options you have pass by thinking outside the box and implement a program who do the job.

For instance, a good implementation could be using the [app.activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method who allow you to check if there is a window with certain name "alive".

If you opt for following this path, the solution would be to create a vbs file called "waitForAll.vbs" (for instance) and provide something like this:

```
Dim objShell
dim found
dim nCount

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

found = true 
nCount = 100  ' to avoid hangings
do while found and nCount > 0 
   found = objShell.appActivate("CAPTION OF YOUR WINRAR WINDOWS")
   wscript.sleep 5 * 1000 ' sleep for five seconds 
   nCount = nCount - 1
loop ' found 

if not found then 
  ' launch whatever
end if ' not found
```

And instead of that start "" d:\ you have to insert a call to this "waitForAll.vbs" program: the program will look for all the windows in the userspace that are called similar that the ones of the winrar: when they aren't found, it will start whatever you want.

Optionally, if a winrar window hangs (with a popup message or something like that), this program eventually end via the nCount counter.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong. Batch is more powerful than you expect ;-) Check out my answer.

Comment: Yes, I read it just after finishing writing mine. Very good solution :D