# Waiting for a sub process in python which creates other processes

Tags: python, batch-file, operating-system, energyplus

I'm using python to launch an EnergyPlus batch simulation using "RunDirMulti.bat". This bat file creates one process for each simulation file on the directory. 
RunDirMulti looks like this:

```
@echo off
: This batch file is used to run EnergyPlus simulations using the RunEPlus.bat for all 
: the files in the current directory across multiple separate processor cores.  It has  
: two parameters, the weather file name to use for simulations and the number of 
: processors.
:
:   RunDirMulti <weather file> (opt) <number processor cores> (opt)
: 
: The RunDirMulti batch file loops through the files located in the current directory 
: and puts RunEPlus calls to each file into as many temporary batch files as processor  
: cores and then starts each of the batch files. No load balancing between the cores 
: is achieved using this method. The RunDirMulti.bat file should be located in a 
: directory that contains the IDF files.

: Main routine
: maindir - change if you did not install in default folder (to be safe, use quotes)
SET maindir="E:\PROGRAMAS\EnergyPlusV8-4-0\"
: The default weather file name if not provided as an argument.
SET weather=ECU_Quito.840710_IWEC
: The default number of separate processor cores that the simulations should use if 
: not provided as an argument.
SET numProc=4
IF "%1" NEQ "" SET weather=%1
IF "%2" NEQ "" SET numProc=%2
SET count=0
: Loop through the temporary directories and delete the temporary batch files.
for /L %%G in (1,1,%numProc%) do call :clean1 %%G
: Loop through each filename and divides them into each temporary batch file.
for %%F in (.\*.idf) do call :divide1  "%%F" 
: Loop through each temporary directory and adds EXIT to each temporary batch file.
for /L %%G in (1,1,%numProc%) do echo EXIT >> .\tempsim%%G\simpart%%G.bat
: Loop through each temporary directory and starts the batch file in a new window 
for /L %%G in (1,1,%numProc%) do call :startEach1 %%G
: The following line goes to the end of the batch file.
GOTO:eof


: Subroutine that deletes the temporary batch files from each
: working directory.
:clean1
IF EXIST .\tempsim%1\simpart%1.bat (
  DEL .\tempsim%1\simpart%1.bat
) ELSE (
  MD .\tempsim%1
)
: The following line returns to the main routine.
GOTO:eof


: Subroutine that takes the file name and uses a counter
: and the MOD operator (double percent) to group them
: into as many batch files as necessary.
:divide1
SET /a count="count + 1"
SET /a group="count %% numProc + 1"
echo CALL %maindir%RunEPlus.bat "%~dpn1"     %weather% >>.\tempsim%group%\simpart%group%.bat 
: The following line returns to the main routine.
GOTO:eof


: Subroutine that starts each batch file
:startEach1
cd .\tempsim%1
START "Batch Simulation%1" simpart%1.bat
cd ..
: The following line returns to the main routine.
GOTO:eof
```

In my script I'm using this

```
p=subprocess.check_call("RunDirMulti.bat")
```

but it does not wait for all the child process to finish. I've already tried Popen and Popen.wait(). Can some one give me an idea please?

Comment: `Popen.wait` waits for the process to finish, the `RunDirMulti.bat` process **does** finish without *wait*ing for it's own child processes to finish so I'd say you just need a batch equivalent to `Popen.wait`, maybe something from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368450/how-to-make-batch-wait-for-multiple-subprocesses

Comment: It seems that they look in the tasklist to see if WinRar is open. In my case I would look for CommandPromt which it will be open as it is the program executing the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it creating a function that checks if cmd is open (in my case i'm running ipython notebook so there is already one cmd open all the time).

```
def running():
    n=0 #number of cmd instances running 
    prog=[line.split() for line in subprocess.check_output("tasklist").splitlines()]
    [prog.pop(e) for e in [0,1,2]] #useless 
    for task in prog:
        if task[0]=="cmd.exe":
            n=n+1
    if n>1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This should work with any program.

Answer (score 0):

When the process is complete you could output a done file via your batch script:

```
type NUL > done.txt
```

Then add something like the following to your python script

```
import os
import time

done_file_path = r'C:\Users\user\done.txt'
while not os.path.exists(done_file_path):
    print "Done file not created, Sleeping for 10 seconds"
    time.sleep(10) # Sleep 10 second
os.remove(done_file_path) # Remove Done file, so next run is successful
```

Adjust the path(C:\Users\user\done.txt) to where you would be outputting the done file of course.

Comment: Then you would have to delete the file every time it runs or it will incorrectly think it is finished because the file still exists.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks, I've adjusted accordingly.